# Better way to "deburr" an object

Tags: modeling

I have an object like so with pointy spikes:
[image]

And there's a lot of them all over the object.  Also I have no control over how they were created/the object modelling.  I'd like to get rid of them all at once and "smooth" them, but when I use the smoothing tool in sculpt mode, it often makes them worse:

[image]

I can go after each spike individually and in edit mode remove the vertices, fill the holes, etc...   but is there a tool I don't know about?

Blender 2.92

Comment: Hello :). You  might have some luck with one of the Remeshing tools.

Comment: @JachymMichal  Which tool do you think?

Comment: Hey :). Either the Remesh modifier, or the Voxel remesher :).